# 401 Unauthorized on dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox

I am trying to build a python application able to download a file chunk by chunk in python, I am using the package `dropbox-python` for the whole application but in the case of downloading a file chunk by chunk, the package does not handle the case.

So I am trying to use the `dropbox.rest.RESTClient.request` to make the request, and use the headers parameter to pass the Range.
I am using the `dropbox.client.DropboxClient.request` to retrieve all the informations I need to build the request in term of Oauth1.0.

So what I have at the end is the following URL : https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/bigfile?oauth_token=(token)&oauth_consumer_key=(consumer_key)

When I try to send the request I get a 401 Unauthorized.
Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
def download_big_file(self, filename, outDir=None):

    fname = filename
    metadata = self.client.metadata(fname)
    size = metadata['bytes']
    url, params, headers = self.client.request("/files/dropbox/"+filename)
    url = url.replace("api", "api-content")
    url = url + "?oauth_token=" + params['oauth_token'] + "&oauth_consumer_key=" + params['oauth_consumer_key']

    if outDir:
        dst = os.path.join(outDir, fname)
else:
        dst = fname

    endchunk = self.chunked_file_size
    with open(fname, "wb") as fh:
        try:
            while endchunk < size:
                fh.write(dropbox.rest.RESTClient.request('GET', url, headers={"Range": "bytes="+str(endchunk-self.chunked_file_size)+"-"+str(endchunk)}))
            endchunk += self.chunked_file_size
        except Exception, e:
            print "ERROR: ", e

    return dst, metadata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a library called `dropbox-python`? Or is this just `dropbox`, the [official library from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python)?

If it's the official library, I think this code should work (untested):

```
url, params, headers = self.client.request(path, {}, method='GET', content_server=True)
headers['Range'] = 'bytes=' + ...
f = self.client.rest_client.request("GET", url, headers=headers, raw_response=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this was the official library from Dropbox, but I have another problem, when I do the request the result is printed on my console whithout doing any print. Did you already have this problem?

Comment: No, I've never seen anything like that. Maybe you can create a minimal version of your app and share the code so I can try it myself?